# sstableloader fails to execute, requires permissions on /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I am trying to run `sstableloader` on my Yum based DataStax 6.8.30 version cluster to transfer sstables to another Yum based DataStax 6.8.30 version cluster. The dse service on both the setups was spawned under a non-root account (`cassUser`) by doing `sudo service dse start`.

I am executing sstableloader command under same non-root Linux account user.

```
[cassUser@vm104 root]$ sstableloader -cph 1  -d *.*.*.* -t 10000 --no-progress -f /etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra.yaml /var/lib/cassandra/data/k1/emp-500bb8a0805e11edae2fc5fa144e78f6/
WARNING: commitlog directory '/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog' or, if it does not already exist, an existing parent directory of it, is not readable and writable for the DSE. Check file system and configuration.
NOTE: DSE tools should be run by a user with permissions to operate on DSE data directories (for example the user that DSE runs as, which is typically 'cassandra').
ERROR 10:56:07,885 Exception in thread Thread[main,5,main]
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: commitlog directory '/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog' or, if it does not already exist, an existing parent directory of it, is not readable and writable for the DSE. Check file system and configuration.
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.resolveAndCheckDirectory(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1287)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applySimpleConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:730)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.toolInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:293)
        at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.initDseToolMode(DseDaemon.java:252)
        at com.datastax.bdp.tools.ShellToolWrapper.execute(ShellToolWrapper.java:149)
        at com.datastax.bdp.tools.ShellToolWrapper.main(ShellToolWrapper.java:78)
```

I suppose it is because of `cassUser` trying to execute the sstableloader and commit log folder does not have write permissions by default for other users.

```
[cassUser@vm104 tmp]$ ls -ld /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/
drwxr-xr-x. 2 cassandra cassandra 84 Dec 20 17:30
/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/
```

But, this is the same user which was added to sudoers list and was used to spawn the dse service. How to get this executed?

Comment: Hi @RadhaWadhera, thank you for your question. What is the end goal that you're trying to achieve here? Moving data between two clusters? Do you have [OpsCenter](https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/docs/6.8/about_c.html) installed that is managing these two DSE clusters? What's the output of executing `ls -l /var/lib|grep cassandra` & `ls -lr /var/lib/cassandra` commands?

Comment: You're right that `cassUser` doesn't have permission on those directories leveraged by DSE process which was started by `cassandra` user. You'll notice the user that started the DSE process by running `ps -ef|grep -i dse` command on the DSE cluster node from where you're running the sstableloader operation.

Comment: Hi @Madhavan, Thanks for your response. I don't have OpsCenter installed. I had installed DSE clusters manually using Yum. I am trying to move data between two clusters using sstableloader. I am still not sure why does it need permissions on commit log , metadata folder etc. 
This command **ps -ef|grep -i dse** shows **cassandra** user .
Is there a way to get this executed?

Comment: Output of **ls -lr /var/lib/cassandra**


`[cassUser@vm104]$ ls -lr /var/lib/cassandra
total 4
drwxr-xr-x.  2 cassandra cassandra    6 Dec  9 21:20 saved_caches
drwxr-xr-x.  3 cassandra cassandra   19 Dec 20 17:32 metadata
drwxr-xr-x.  3 cassandra cassandra   22 Dec 20 17:32 insights_data
drwxr-xr-x.  2 cassandra cassandra    6 Aug 22 13:16 hints
drwxr-xr-x. 17 cassandra cassandra 4096 Dec 23 09:30 data
drwxr-xr-x.  2 cassandra cassandra   84 Dec 23 09:23 commitlog`

Comment: Output of **ls -l /var/lib|grep cassandra**


`[cassUser@vm104]$ ls -l /var/lib|grep cassandra
drwxr-xr-x. 11 cassandra      cassandra       186 Dec 20 17:32 cassandra
drwxr-xr-x.  3 cassandra      cassandra        18 Dec 19 17:03 datastax-agent
drwx------.  2 cassandra      cassandra         6 Dec  9 21:20 dsefs
drwxr-xr-x.  4 cassandra      cassandra        31 Dec 20 10:18 spark`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install [DataStax Enterprise](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise) (DSE) as an [RPM package](https://docs.datastax.com/en/installing/docs/installRHELdse.html), DSE will be automatically configured to run with the Linux user `cassandra`. As you have already discovered, all files are owned by the user `cassandra`. This is normal and is expected when you install the DSE package.

When you start or stop the DSE service with:

```
$ sudo dse service [start|stop]
```

the startup/shutdown scripts get executed as `cassandra` user even when you execute the command as `cassUser`. If you look closely at the `/etc/init.d/dse` script, you'll see that it forks a shell (`-s /bin/sh`) as the `cassandra` user with the `su` command (substitute user) to start the DSE process:

```
        su $CASSANDRA_USER -s /bin/sh -c "$dse_CMD -H \"$heap_dump_f\" -E \"$error_log_f\" > \"$OUTPUT_FILE\" 2>&1"
```

You will need to run `sstableloader` as the `cassandra` user, for example:

```
$ sudo -u cassandra sstableloader ...
```

or whatever variation you prefer. Cheers!

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over the [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra) tag then click on the `Watch tag` button.  Thanks!

Comment: `Thanks a lot @Erick Ramirez! This works with sudo.`